# where is the problem with port 22?

Tags: ssh, vpn

I want to connect with my university and use a cluster.
I connect via vpn with university.Now i want to connect with the cluster with ssh protocol.
I  have the ip,so in a terminal i write "ssh ip" (of the cluster)
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out

what may be wrong ?

Comment: Can you ping that ip?

Comment: i write ping 195.xx.xx.x.                                      PING xxx.xxx.xxx.xx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xx) 56(84) bytes of data.       after that nothing happens

Comment: Your problem isn't with the port 22 or ssh, your problem is that you have no connection to that IP, maybe firewall problem or other thing.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like a general networking issue than anything wrong with SSH itself. I'd try:

- Pinging known hosts on the network
- Using a tool like whatismyip.com to make sure you're really on the VPN
- If they both work, trying to access other protocols on other servers in the remote network (most Universities have an intranet, for example).
- Use IPs when possible. If you're using mDNS or a local DNS server (inside the remote network) this can mess around with things especially if your computer has cached an external DNS record (which doesn't line up with the VPN-internal version). I'm not explaining that particularly well, but try an IP if you're currently using a domain name.

If you know you're on the VPN properly and can access other network services, that's when it's time to ping your IT department an email. There *could* be a policy to segregate VPN connections from the cluster for security reasons and they're likely the people who will know about it.

Comment: yesterday it works!without do anything.Today the same problem! why?